# unable to sign up for parse.com to create an app in order get the APP ID for my iOS app

Tags: parse-platform

I've been trying to sign up for Parse.com, but whenever I click "I don't have a Parse account" it just takes me back to the main page! If I try logging in with Facebook or Google or GitHub, it does the same. I even tried "Get started for free" in the development section. When I click that button, nothing happens AT ALL! Help??

Comment: FYI - Parse is shutting down in about 11 months. You may want to find a different solution.

Comment: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: Oh thank you so much @rmaddy. Suggest any other good backend services like parse? Please?

Comment: Thank you @RohitChatterjee too! Can you too suggest me the same?

Comment: This site is not for recommendations. Such questions are off-topic here.

Comment: You should google "backend as a service". Off the top of my head - Kinvey, Bluemix and AWS

Answer (score 1):

Parse is closing down and disable new user creating an account. You can check out some Parse alternatives such as Apple CloudKit (https://developer.apple.com/icloud/) or AWS Mobile Hub or Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/)
Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you sir! I'll check out both. Thanks a lot!